# How to get the UIApplication instance from SBApplication with private api in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-privateapi, tweak, springboard

I can get the `SBApplication` instance of the frontmost application, but I need use the instance of `UIApplication`, just as the result of `[UIApplication sharedInstance]`, but how can I get the `UIApplication` instance from `SBApplication`?Thank you!

```
SBApplication *currentApplication = (SBApplication *)[(SpringBoard *)[objc_getClass("SpringBoard") sharedApplication] _accessibilityFrontMostApplication];
```